# Annotated beans not getting injected for JAX-RS CXF service

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I have a CXF RESTful service which is working just fine.  Problem is when I try to inject my DAO using an annotation:

```
@Resource
private MyDAO myDAO;
```

It's not getting injected.  My JAX-RS service is Spring configured like so:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
      xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
      xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">


  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml"/>
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

  <jaxrs:server id="message" serviceClass="com.foo.MessageResourceImpl" address="/">
    <jaxrs:features>
         <cxf:logging/>
    </jaxrs:features>
  </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

The DAO is getting initialized by Spring and I have verified the bean works in any other POJO, just not the CXF service.  Furthermore, I don't see any errors in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to serviceBeans:

```
<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <bean class="com.foo.MessageResourceImpl"/>
</jaxrs:serviceBeans>
```

When using @serviceClass, CXF instantiates the class, not Spring.

Comment: Is it possible to autodiscover that beans as I ask in this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520821/autodiscover-jax-rs-resources-with-cxf-in-a-spring-application ?