# "org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.bus.providers" not working

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, bus

I'm creating 2 REST containers using . I want to keep some common things like the JSON providers, validation interceptor, exception handling using a cxf bus. below is my application context.

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:properties>
       <entry key="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider" key-ref="busProviders"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:bus>

  <util:list id="busProviders">
    <ref bean="requestInterceptor"/>
    <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    <ref bean="exceptionHandler"/>
  </util:list>

<bean id="requestInterceptor" class="com.sample.interceptor.ServiceValidationInterceptor"/>
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
<bean id="exceptionHandler" class="com.sample.exception.ExceptionHandler" />

<!-- ======================== REST Container for Service1 ======================================= -->
 <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/service1">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="endecaService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpInInterceptor">
            <property name="callbackParam" value="callback"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpPreStreamInterceptor">
            <property name="mediaType" value="application/json"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpPostStreamInterceptor">
            <property name="paddingEnd" value=")"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxrs:outInterceptors>   
  </jaxrs:server>  

  <!-- ======================== REST Container for Service2========================================== -->
<jaxrs:server id="restContainerForHelpcenter" address="/service2">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="helpCenter"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpInInterceptor">
            <property name="callbackParam" value="callback"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpPreStreamInterceptor">
            <property name="mediaType" value="application/json"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpPostStreamInterceptor">
            <property name="paddingEnd" value=")"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxrs:outInterceptors> 
  </jaxrs:server>
```

If I combine the above 2  into a single  with 2 service beans, then it works fine, but not in this case. 
Has anybody used the cxf:bus feature for 2 different REST containers, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Notice `s` in the end of the property name org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.bus.provider**s**

Answer (score 0):

#### The long story

I had a similar problem:

I want to use autodiscovery for the JAX-RS service beans, but if I use a `<jaxrs:providers>` tag inside the `<jaxrs:server>` tag but no `<jaxrs:serviceBeans>` tag, autodiscovery is simply not used.

This means I have to use autodiscovery for the JAX-RS providers as well, which wasn’t difficult for the two that are below our base package (for the Spring component scan) since they were already annotated `@Provider`. However, this doesn’t work as easily for Jackson (and there are good reasons to *not* include Jackson in the Spring component scan, as it will pick up too *much* as the package contains several annotated classes).

So I had to hang up the Jackson provider on the CXF bus. I found the docs, which weren’t helpful, and your post, which gave me part of the answer. I did need several iterations of cursing, learning about `xsi:schemaLocation` and all that, but in the end, I did it:

#### tl;dr

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.basepackage"/>
<!-- … -->
        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
        <jaxrs:server address="/"/>
        <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
        <cxf:bus>
                <cxf:properties>
                        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.providers" value-ref="busProviders"/>
                </cxf:properties>
        </cxf:bus>
        <util:list id="busProviders">
                <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
        </util:list>
</beans>
```

#### … ?

The snippet I’ve elided is comprised of just a few manual bean definitions like these:

```
        <bean id="wadlGenerator" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
                <property name="linkAnyMediaTypeToXmlSchema" value="true"/>
        </bean>
```

So the snippet I posted *might* be enough to get one started.