# Separating spring cxf jaxrs:server definition into multiple xml files

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I have the following cxf spring jaxrs:server definition for my REST endpoints:

```
<jaxrs:server id="my-server" address="/address">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="bean1"/>
        <ref bean="bean2"/>
        <ref bean="bean3"/>   
        <ref bean="bean4"/>
        <ref bean="bean5"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I need to split up the REST endpoint definitions into multiple modules within my project. For example:

server-config1.xml

```
<jaxrs:server id="my-server" address="/address">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="bean1"/>
        <ref bean="bean2"/>
        <ref bean="bean3"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

server-config2.xml

```
<jaxrs:server id="my-server" address="/address">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="bean4"/>
        <ref bean="bean5"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

The two projects are built as bundles deployed into Jboss Fuse. The first bundle deploys and successfully starts. The second bundle fails with an error that the address is already in use.

How can I reference/reuse an existing jaxrs:server definition from one spring config file within another? I can't simply change the address of the second server definition as all my code will then need to change. Note that both server definitions will not always be installed as one may not be available (different clients get different endpoints). Each REST endpoint already has a unique @Path definition.

I am using CXF v2.7

Comment: I do not see an easy way to solve your problem. Once the JaxRs Server is [created](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.7.x/index.html?org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/JAXRSServerFactoryBean.html) you can not add new beans. A possible way would be to keep an reference to the Factory  and add new beans on demand and start a new server, while stopping the old. I am not sure of this fits your use case. Generally it sounds as if your idea and your use case are not a perfect match.

Comment: Do you think you can provide a sample on how to do what you described? I am open to not using spring and doing everything programmatically.

Comment: You should edit your question to elaborate more on your use case and your environment.

Comment: I'm willing to accept/implement any solution that helps me achieve what I need. The question is my use case.

Comment: Its hard to tell without knowing your environment. Might it be possible to just have different ports for the different modules ? If you have any kind of proxy in front of your server*s* you could forward based on paths to different ports.

Comment: That's definitely an option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520821/autodiscover-jax-rs-resources-with-cxf-in-a-spring-application