# How to register CXF Rest services

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, cxf

I have a Spring MVC application and I'm trying to expose REST service using CXF (Jax-RS). I can't understand how to register my service and make it available. Here is my service:

```
@Path("/myservice/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface MyService {

        @POST
        @Path("start")
        public String start(){
          ...........
        }
    }
```

So far I've managed to avoid any configuration file, only using annotations. So how do I expose my service without a config file? I couldn't find the information in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer. Bits and parts can be found [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520821/autodiscover-jax-rs-resources-with-cxf-in-a-spring-application), but nowhere had a complete answer that's easy to follow/implement.

I'll skip the maven part since it's pretty easy to figure it out.

**Register CXF Servlet**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/*")
public class CXFStartServlet extends CXFServlet {
}
```

**Register all the Spring beans with @Path as a CXF service**

```
@Configuration
public class MyCxfConfig {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;

@Bean(name="cxf")
public SpringBus springBus(){
    return new SpringBus();
}

@Bean
public Server jaxRsServer() {
    LinkedList<ResourceProvider> resourceProviders = new LinkedList<ResourceProvider>();
    for (String beanName : ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        if (ctx.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, Path.class) != null) {
            SpringResourceFactory factory = new SpringResourceFactory(beanName);
            factory.setApplicationContext(ctx);
            resourceProviders.add(factory);
        }
    }

    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    factory.setBus(ctx.getBean(SpringBus.class));
    factory.setProviders(Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider()));
    factory.setResourceProviders(resourceProviders);
    return factory.create();
}
}
```

Don't forget to import "MyCxfconfig" in your Spring config. That's all :)